# Python reformatting strings based on contents

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

In a pandas dataframe I have rows with contents in the following format:

```
1) abc123-Target 4-ufs
2) abc123-target4-ufs
3) geo.4
4) j123T4
```

All of these should be simply: target 4

So far my cleaning procedure is as follows:

```
df["point_id"] = df["point_id"].str.lower()
df["point_id"] = df['point_id'].str.replace('^.*?(?=target)', '')
```

This returns:

```
1) target 4-ufs
2) target4-ufs
3) geo.14
4) geo.2
5) j123T4
```

What I believe I need is:

```
a. Remove anything after the last number in the string, this solves 1
b. If 'target' does not have a space after it add a space, this with the above solves 2
c. If the string ends in a point and a number of any length remove everything before the point (incl. point) and replace with 'target ', this solves 3 and 4
d. If the string ends with a 't' followed by a number of any length remove everything before 't' and replace with 'target ', this solves 5
```

I'm looking at regex and re but the following is not having effect (add space before the last number)

```
df["point_id"] = re.sub(r'\D+$', '', df["point_id"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the rules, you might use 2 capture groups and check for the group values:

```
\btarget\s*(\d+)|.*[t.](\d+)$
```

- `\btarget\s*(\d+)` Match target, optional whitespace chars and capture 1+ digits in **group 1**
- `|` Or
- `.*[t.]` Match 0+ characters followed by either t or a `.`
- `(\d+)$` Capture 1+ digits in **group 2** at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCg7BS/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/04YOdC)

Python example:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = r"\btarget\s*(\d+)|.*[t.](\d+)$"
strings = [
    "abc123-Target 4-ufs",
    "abc123-target4-ufs",
    "geo.4",
    "j123T4"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["point_id"])

def change(s):
    m = re.search(pattern, s, re.IGNORECASE)
    return "target " + (m.group(2) if m.group(2) else m.group(1))

df["point_id"] = df["point_id"].apply(change)
print(df)
```

Output

```
   point_id
0  target 4
1  target 4
2  target 4
3  target 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'point_id':['abc123-Target 4-ufs','abc123-target4-ufs','geo.4','j123T4']})
df['point_id'] = df['point_id'].str.replace(r'(?i).*Target\s*(\d+).*', r'target \1', regex=True)
df.loc[df['point_id'].str.contains(r'(?i)\w[.t]\d+$'), 'point_id'] = 'target 4'
#    point_id
# 0  target 4
# 1  target 4
# 2  target 4
# 3  target 4
```

The regex is `(?i)Target\s*\d+|\w+[.t]\d+$`:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `Target\s*(\d+).*` - `Target`, zero or more whitespaces, and one or more digits captured into Group 1
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

The second regex matches

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching
- `\w` - a word char, then
- `[.t]` - a `.` or `t` and then
- `\d+$` - one or more digits at the end of string.

The second regex is used as a mask, and the values in the `point_id` column are set to `target 4` whenever the pattern matches the regex.

See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG4oNm/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG4oNm/3).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer over writes the target number with `target 4` which was only an example. The answer by @The fourth bird gives a complete answer. But thank you for the explanation, appreciated.

Comment: @SpatialDigger I updated the answer. Solved in two lines of code.